# AngularJS. Directive' isolated scope, pushing a value from parent scope

Tags: angularjs

I try to pass a value from `parent scope` to my `directive`. To its `isolated scope`. It works ok if I pass values as argument to my directive. But id does not work for parent scope.

Here is how I use it:

```
<div ng-init="event='hello'">  <!-- this is parent scope -->

    <input31></input31>

</div>
```

Here is the directive itself.

```
directives.directive("input31", [function() {    
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:"<div> <input type='text' ng-model='data' /> {{data}} </div>",
        replace: true,
        scope : { //defining isolated scope
            event: "=event"  // pushing value to isolated directive scope
        }
    }

}]);
```

**In the end I'm expecting to have `event` var filled by 'hello' value but I have `null`**

**update**

I thought that it's possible to select/filter what to use from parent scope, kind of filter. Like if in parent scope I have a,b,c then specifying 'scope {a: '=a'}' I could transfer only 'a' from parent scope. But as I understand this not the way to go. **this work only if passing values as directive arguments (?)**

Answer (score 4):

Using an **isolate scope binding** you'll need to pass the value in as an attribute on the directive.

```
<input31 event=event></input31>
```

This can be a plus from a documentation/maintenance standpoint.

But, **if you really don't want to pass it in as an attribute**, but otherwise want an isolate scope, then instead of using a binding you can copy the value off the parent's scope inside the directive's link function.

```
link: function ($scope) {
    $scope.event = $scope.$parent.event;
}
```

If you do this then you don't need to pass it in via the isolate scope, so the directive's scope can look like this:

```
scope : { 
        },
```

Comment: I thought that it's possible to select/filter what to use from parent scope, kind of filter. Like if in parent scope I have a,b,c then specifying 'scope {a: '=a'}' I could transfer only 'a' from parent scope. But as I understand this not the way to go.

Comment: You're right that you can do exactly that. But you have to both specify it in the scope and specify the mapping on the directive. Those two pieces work together.  Here's a good couple minute overview:http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **existing scope** from directive's DOM element. You can do do this by either:

1. Setting scope as `false`
2. Not setting scope at all (*by default scope is set to false*).

Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GordyD/NCPkw/) for an example.

Your directive could then be defined like this:

```
app.directive('input31', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:"<div> <input type='text' ng-model='event' /> {{event}} </div>",
        replace: true,
        scope : false // or omit this line
    };
});
```

If you require an **isolated scope** then you have to specify what values to bind from the parent scope. You can do this in two ways:

1. Pass specific attributes to your directive's isolated scope e.g. `<input31 event="event">`
2. Reference the parent scope directly in your directive. e.g. `$scope.$parent.event`

Comment: Updated my question. (That what you're pointing I've already knew)

Answer (score 0):

I've put an example of what I have been asking.

https://github.com/Sergey80/angularjs-examples/blob/master/public/examples/directive_isolate_scope/sample6_at_sign.html

There is way to use parent scope from within Perent scope.